# How to create a json file in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am needing to create a JSON file from scratch that will look like this

```
{
 "results": {
  "course": "CC167",
  "books": {
   "book": [
    {
      "-id": "585457",
      "-title": "Beginning XNA 20 game programming : from novice to professional",
      "-isbn": "1590599241",
      "-borrowedcount": "16"
    },
    {
      "-id": "325421",
      "-title": "Red Hat Linux 6",
      "-isbn": "0201354373",
      "-borrowedcount": "17"
    },
    {
      "-id": "424317",
      "-title": "Beginner's guide to darkBASIC game programming",
      "-isbn": "1592000096",
      "-borrowedcount": "46"
    },
    {
      "-id": "437390",
      "-title": "Objects first with Java : a practical introduction using BlueJ",
      "-isbn": "0131249339",
      "-borrowedcount": "89"
    },
    {
      "-id": "511094",
      "-title": "Objects first with Java : a practical introduction using BlueJ",
      "-isbn": "2006044765",
      "-borrowedcount": "169"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

This is the PHP i used to make that, so hopefully it isn't a big jump, but I just can't anything on how to make JSON objects in PHP from scratch, only how to make something like this then save it as a JSON yourself

```
$y = 1;
    $json = "{";
    $json = $json . "\"results\": {";
    $json = $json . "\"course\": \"$cc\",";
    $json = $json . "\"books\": {";
    $json = $json . "\"book\": [";
    foreach ($my_array as $counter => $bc) {
        $json = $json . "{";
        $json = $json . "\"-id\": \"$id[$counter]\",";
        $json = $json . "\"-title\": \"$title[$counter]\",";
        $json = $json . "\"-isbn\": \"$isbn[$counter]\",";
        $json = $json . "\"-borrowedcount\": \"$borrowedcount[$counter]\"";
        $json = $json . "}";
        if ($x != $y) $json = $json .  ",";
        $json = $json . "";
        $y++;
    }
    $json = $json . "]";
    $json = $json . "}";
    $json = $json . "}";
    $json = $json . "}";
    echo $json;
```

Comment: Where's the PHP that you used to create it?  As for creating JSON in PHP look at [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: You don't make 'JSON objects' and manipulate those, you *output* data as JSON.

Comment: json_encode() just google ...

Comment: @mpm we had usenet news groups, bbs and had to try and then fail , try again etc... :)

Comment: What PHP version are you using? You don't to use that obnoxious syntax when `json_*` are available.

Answer (score 4):

You can generate json from an array in PHP using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

For example this would generate something similar to your json above (slightly cut down)

```
$data = array(
  "results" => array(
    "course" => "CC167",
    "books" => array(
      "book" =>
      array(
        array(
          "-id" => "585457",
          "-title" => "Beginning XNA 20 game programming : from novice to professional",
          "-isbn" => "1590599241",
          "-borrowedcount" => "16"
        ),
        array(
          "-id" => "325421",
          "-title" => "Red Hat Linux 6",
          "-isbn" => "0201354373",
          "-borrowedcount" => "17"
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Trying to generate json by manual string concatenation (as in your current code) is bad idea as its hard to avoid syntax errors and you need to be escaping dynamic parts of the json. json_encode automatically does that escaping for you.

Comment: Nice that the answer follows the field names in the original question, but @Craig Weston I wonder, why are you prefixing the book fields with a hyphen? It's quite unusual to have property names start with a hyphen in Javascript and makes it impossible to use dot syntax (e.g. you must do `book['-id']` instead of `book.id`)

Comment: The "array(
          "-id" => "585457",
          "-title" => "Beginning XNA 20 game programming : from novice to professional",
          "-isbn" => "1590599241",
          "-borrowedcount" => "16"
        )"

Is the only problem, as there could be just one entry or loads, how would i add more arrays into this, and ensure their correct placement>

Comment: @CraigWeston I've update the answer to show adding a 2nd book entry. None of this is specific to creating json, its just standard PHP array creation. json_encode() just reproduces the nested array structure as a json string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array       = array("test"=>"value");

$json_string = json_encode($array);
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: That would incode a small part into one node (Iunno what the JSON terminal is, i know XML more) i need to create a film that has a lot of nodes, and that is the problem i am finding, i can make one line, but i can't find any way to build a entire document.