# How to create an JSON file in php/javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I Want to create an JSON file in the following format. I'm new to the JSON so i can't get how to create this data displayed in the JSON format. Thanks in advance

```
{
            "data": [
                [
                    "Tiger Nixon",
                    "System Architect",
                    "Edinburgh",
                    "5421",
                    "2011\/04\/25",
                    "$320,800"
                ],
                [
                    "Garrett Winters",
                    "Accountant",
                    "Tokyo",
                    "8422",
                    "2011\/07\/25",
                    "$170,750"
                ],
                [
                    "Ashton Cox",
                    "Junior Technical Author",
                    "San Francisco",
                    "1562",
                    "2009\/01\/12",
                    "$86,

    000"
            ],
    [
                "Donna Snider",
                "Customer Support",
                "New York",
                "4226",
                "2011\/01\/25",


"$112,000"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Haven't you read anything ? Here is some starting point : http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Comment: No i have search the Stackoverflow.com https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060887/how-to-create-a-json-file-in-php but its different in the format.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can start like this :

```
$str = '{
    "data": [
        [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011\/04\/25", "$320,800" ],
        [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011\/07\/25", "$170,750" ],
        [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009\/01\/12", "$86,000" ],
        [ "Donna Snider", "Customer Support", "New York", "4226", "2011\/01\/25", "$112,000" ]
    ]
}';

$json = json_decode($str);
$res = $json->{'data'};

foreach($res as $data) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
}
```

Comment: I try to fetch that JSON data's from the database..

Comment: Can the downvoter explain why ?